# Why cannot assign a subtype value to a generic type?

Tags: java, generics

Could anybody explain:

```
class Test<T extends BaseDao>{

    void someMethod(){
        T inst = new Dao();      // required type T provided Dao
        T inst2 = new BaseDao(); // required type T provided BaseDao
    }

}

class Dao extends BaseDao{}
```

We have T type as a subtype of BaseDao.
Why cannot assign Dao or BaseDao types to T type?

Comment: Because if `T` is some _other_ subtype of `BaseDao` then the assignment would be invalid. If you're requiring `T` to be `Dao` specifically, then it's not a generic parameter.

Comment: Because a `Dog` is an `Animal` but an `Animal` is not always a `Dog`, likewise: type `T` is a type that extends `BaseDao`, but not everything that is or extends `BaseDao` is a `T`.

Comment: that is it! thanks a lot!

Comment: You might want to look at `T super BaseDao`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine

```
Test<MySpecialDao> specialDao = new Test<>();
```

Now, for a call like `specialDao.someMethod()`,

```
void someMethod(){
    T inst = new Dao();      // required type T, provided Dao
    T inst2 = new BaseDao(); // required type T, provided BaseDao
}
```

effectively becomes

```
void someMethod(){
    MySpecialDao inst = new Dao();      // required type MySpecialDao, provided Dao
    MySpecialDao inst2 = new BaseDao(); // required type MySpecialDao, provided BaseDao
}
```

and of course, both `Dao` and `BaseDao` aren't subtypes of `MySpecialDao`, probably supertypes.

I'd change to

```
void someMethod(){
    Dao inst = new Dao(); 
    BaseDao inst2 = new BaseDao();
}
```

hoping that this change doesn't break your intended logic.

Answer (score 0):

T can be an instance of Dao, but you cannot assign a new istance of Dao to the generic type T like this because T could refer to any class extending BaseDao.

If you need to have some specific instance of Dao you should do

```
Dao inst = new Dao()
```

If instead you do want a specific instance, but you don't want to know the specific class, you could pass inst1 and inst2 as parameters, or pass a string and create an instance by name, or many other possibility.

In short, `T inst = new Dao();` makes no sense because it collides with the purpose of generics.